# Create initial data sqlscripts with binary data, sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, scripting, binary-data

with a TFS 2008 Teambuildtype we create a ClickOnce Setup for a review version of our application.
Within this Teambuildtype we create an initial database with some data to start directly with tests.

Now i need to put some binary data in our sql script insert files (Wordfiles).

How can i create a initial script with the binary data ?
I can't put the binary string into a script or?

Thanks a lot

**Edit:
Found a solution with OpenRowset**

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Doc) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\File.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as ImageToInsert
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you already found a solution that works for you that just bumped this question but you **can** put binary data in a script.

Just use `0x....` to denote a binary data literal.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable(Doc)
VALUES (0x474946383961500...)
```

Comment: Oh, dont know it. I think i can use this way in the future.

Comment: @K.Hoffmann - If you already have the data in a table on your development machine you can use the (free) [SSMS Tools Pack Addin](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) to script it out easily.

Comment: that looks nice, i just send it to some colleagues @work. ty again